# How to add attribute in fabric objects

Tags: vue.js, canvas, nuxt.js, fabricjs

I will add editable attribute to image object in fabric but I try `console.log(canvas.toJSON())` then It's not showing editable attribute in object.

**In my code**

```
const image = 'https//www.test.com/test.png'
fabric.Image.fromURL(image, function (patternImage) {
      patternImage.set({
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
      })
      patternImage.scaleToHeight(120)
      patternImage.scaleToWidth(120)
      canvas.add(patternImage)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

FabricJS allows you to pass an array of additional properties into the `toJSON()` method to include them in the serialization.

You can use it like this:

`canvas.toJSON(['editable']);`

See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON